# Xamarin.Forms set ModalInPresentation

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to set the `ModalInPresentation` value from Xamarin.Forms? I can set `On<iOS>().SetModalPresentationStyle(UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet);` on my `ContentPage` but I"m not able to prevent a dismiss of the page for specific cases as I would need it.

Answer (score 0):

> but I"m not able to prevent a dismiss of the page for specific cases as I would need it.

Generally,we can use `ModalInPresentation = true;` to prevernt the page be dismissed in page renderer.

```
public class CustomPageRenderer :PageRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        ModalInPresentation = true;
    }
}
```

It works in Xamarin.iOS. However, it not works in Xamarin Forms now. I will check that where problem is.

Comment: I also would like to be able to use this flag in Xamarin Forms.  I can confirm that it isn't working.  If there is a fix or a workaround, please let us know.

Comment: @btschumy Ok, that's sure.

Comment: @btschumy You can have a try with the lastest version of Xamarin Forms to check whehter it works now. It seems always can prevent a dismiss of the page without doing anything.

Comment: I updated to the latest Xamarin Forms (4.8.0.1364) yesterday and it still is not working.

Comment: @btschumy Okey , could you share your created sample project link here? I will check it in my local site.

Comment: It's an iOS bug. modalInPresentation doesn't work at all at least in iOS 15.

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded a sample project here:

[www.otherwise.com/ModalPresentation.zip](http://www.otherwise.com/ModalPresentation.zip)

The MainPage just has a button that shows a modal panel via:

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new OTNavigationPage(new ModalPage()));
```

OTNavigationPage is a subclass of NavigationPage.  I use it to set the modal presentation style:

```
    On<iOS>().SetModalPresentationStyle(UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet);
```

There is also OTContentPage which exists only so I can have a native renderer to try to set the ModalInPresentation flag to true.  I do this in a variety of places trying to find one that works.  None do.

I expect setting ModalInPresentation = true should prevent the modal panel from being dismissed via swiping.  It does not.

There is also a bug which I think the team knows of where swiping to dismiss corrupts the navigation stack.  If I try to show the modal page again I get:

Warning: Attempt to present <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x10782cc00> on <ModalPresentation_iOS_OTNavigationPageRenderer: 0x107128600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

This post talks about it:  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7364

Comment: I just realized the the project I uploaded was not using the latest Xamarin Forms package.  When I upgrade to the latest, I still have the problem of the ModalInPresentation not being respected.  In addition, I now get the crash I see in my full app.  If you tap outside the modal window and then dismiss it, you get a crash.  This is described here:  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184772/crash-dismissing-a-navigationcontroller-presented-with-uimodalpresentationstyle-formseet#latest